# Docker-volume of webroot not editable on host machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lamp

I have a docker-compose LAMP stack comprised of three services; a webserver, php and mysql.
The apache2 webroot inside the container is shared to my local machine using a volume like so:

```
volumes:          
   - ./public_html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

When the stack is running though, I can't edit files inside of the shared volume, since I  have a different local user as the user inside the apache2 container. Additionally the installer of my CMS (Processwire) is unable to acquire permissions to the required install directories.
The apache container uses alpine 2.4.35.

I've build my docker-compose file according to this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@thivi/creating-a-lamp-stack-using-docker-compose-13ca4e3950e1

Below I have attached my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  apache:
    build: './apache'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      - ./cert/:/usr/local/apache2/cert/
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
  php:
    build: './php'
    restart: always
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./public_html:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
      - ./tmp:/usr/local/tmp
  mysql:
    build: './mysql'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

Is there any way to fix this issue? I'd be grateful for answers, I've been dealing with this issue for the past 2 days, without getting anywhere and I'm also kind of surprised that such an essential feature like directory sharing is so complicated.

/edit:
I've also noticed something interesting; when I execute a bash inside the apache-container the ownership of apache's document root is set to `nobody:nobody`, which probably also isn't right.

Comment: Why not set up an Apache container that runs as root, like the majority of other containers? Otherwise you will have to have either a group or a user in the container and host with the same ID as far as I know. Some tips here if you keep the non-root user: https://medium.com/@nielssj/docker-volumes-and-file-system-permissions-772c1aee23ca

Comment: Having run apache as root should work with the `privileged: true`option, correct? I've tried that as well, which didn't work out for me.